# KitKat (API Level 19) TextView Button does not show text

Tags: android

[][1]When I run my application in kitkat verison text does not appear in textview, button on the navigation bar, spinner. 
The text is in Nepalese. What may be the cause?

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwm3Z.png

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: can i see the code or something ?

Comment: I think you haven't applied the value resources for your particular language. and also you haven't given the default one, Anyway please show your code both xml and Java

Comment: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView,textview this is the error in most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

extend your MainActivity class with AppCompatActivity

To display your text on Navigation bar :

```
 navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);   //displays text of header of nav drawer.
     headerview = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
     tt1 = (TextView) headerview.findViewById(R.id.textview_username);
     tt = (TextView) headerview.findViewById(R.id.textView_emailid);
     img1 = (ImageView) headerview.findViewById(R.id.imageView_userimage);

     tt1.setText("your_text");

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```